# Sublime text is deleting tabulations on a document continuously

Tags: python, sublimetext

I can't work properly with python because Sublime text 2 is deleting indent. if I add and edit another part of the document ST removes again all tabulations. Obviously python throws the error: *IndentationError: unexpected indent*.

How can I adjust this?

Comment: What are `View` -> `Syntax` and `View` -> `Indentation` set to?

Comment: Syntax is python and Indentation on "Tab Width: 4".

Comment: This probably won't solve it, but you should set it to add spaces instead of tabs when you hit the tab key.

Comment: It is possible you are mixing tabs and spaces. I believe python sees tabs as 8 spaces. You could try setting your tab width to 8 and making sure your document still is indented properly. (and then make it only spaces)

Comment: So when you save the document, is *all whitespace* at the start removed? Does the document visibly change?

Comment: 1. I add a tabulation in line 203.
2. Modify other part
3. Tabulation deleted: http://i.imgur.com/EgQGU8r.png

Comment: Is line 203 the empty line with the cursor? Python does not care about indentation on empty lines.

Comment: yes... is the empty line. Happens with absolutely all the tabulations without content. But if I paste this code in the python terminal throws error.

Answer (score 7):

SublimeText clears auto-indent whitespace automatically if the `trim_automatic_white_space` setting is enabled (default). This *only* affects blank lines.

Python does *not* care about whitespace on blank lines; blank lines do not need to match the indentation of the rest of the code. However, if you copy lines to the python interpreter, empty lines signal the end of a block and that block is then compiled; this is *different* from running a saved file directly.

If you see indentation errors when running your python file, you are mixing tabs and spaces *elsewhere* in your code. Run your code with `python -tt modulename.py` to test. For python code, you really want to use spaces *only* (convert tabs to spaces, set sublime to use spaces for indentation).

Comment: Excellent answer to this question! Thank you for your thoroughness @Martijn Pieters